# Issue with ng-class when wrapping an element as an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, wrapper, ng-class, angular-ng-class

I'm wrapping a 3rd party directive as an angular directive. Let's call it `<wrapper>`. I must.

In the template, I have a conditional class on the `<wrapper>`, which looks something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{'conditional-class':conditionalClassBoolean}">
    <element-to-wrap
        ng-class="ngClass"
        other-attributes ... >
    </element-to-wrap>
</div>
```

The inner element has an `ng-class` attribute as well. It should receive its class from the wrapper's scope.

The directive looks something like this:

```
angular...directive('wrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ng-class: '@'
        },
        ...
    };
});
```

This worked fine, until I introduced the conditional class to my template. It also works fine as long I do not pass in a class to the wrapper, so that is would be passed down to the inner element...

The following code works:

```
<wrapper ... ></wrapper>
```

The following code does not work:

```
<wrapper ng-class="apply-this-on-the-inner-element" ... ></wrapper>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at ...
of the expression [apply-this-on-the-inner-element {'conditional-class':conditionalClassBoolean}]
```

It seems like angular lists all the "classes" that had been passed in through `ng-class`, but this happens before it evaluates whether the conditional class should be applied or not.
Is there a way to resolve this?

I tried to separate things with commas and semicolons as well. It did not get applied on the inner element. Only the error message went away.

**UPDATE** (as of 17th of January)

It seems like I was able to reproduce the issue in a simplified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88tt4edq/).

Basically, there is a directive (tobe wrapped), which does not replaces its container tags. Than, there is the wrapping directive, which does.

This is how I ended up having `[ {a} {b} ]` AND `[ a {b} ]` type of class-listings.

Still wondering wether there's an optional solution OR I'm just doing something totally wrong here.

Comment: I was able to resolve it with a cutom attribute on the wrapper: `<wrapper inner-class="apply-this-on-the-inner-element" ... ></wrapper>` And use the `innerClass` variable instead. So, my question is rather theoretical. I'm interested in the solution for the above.